# Spark writing to Elasticsearch slow performance

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark, elasticsearch-hadoop

I seem to have hit a problem in which Spark writing to Elasticsearch is very slow and it takes quite a lot of time (around 15 mins) in making the initial connection, during which both Spark and Elasticsearch remain idle.
There is another [thread](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/spark-connector-performance-issues-with-start-up-time/102634/4) highlighting the same issue in the elastic community but it has been closed without any solution.

**This is how I am writing from Spark to ES:**

`vgDF.write.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql").mode('append').option("es.resource", "demoindex/type1").option("es.nodes", "*ES IP*").save()`

**Spark specifications**

`Spark 2.1.0
3 cpu x 10 gb ram x 6 executors 
running on 3 gce nodesSpark 2.1.0`

**Elasticsearch specifications:**

`8 cpu * 30 gb RAM single node`

**ES Versions:**

`Elasticsearch: 6.2.2
ES-Hadoop: 6.2.2`

For your information, Spark reads data from Cassandra DB, process the results (but this process is quite fast, takes around 1 - 2 mins) and then writes to Elasticsearch.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

**[EDIT]**

I have also tried varying the size of data from millions of records to just 960 records, but the initial delay is still the same (approx 15 mins).

Comment: Is spark and ES on the same cluster?

Comment: Nopes, they are not.

Comment: Sounds like network latency to me

Comment: can you elaborate, why you say it was idle in the first 15 minute? please update the question with that details. @sramalingam24 network latency doesnt seem to solve the 15 min initial delay question.

Comment: I don't think it's because of network latency. I have tried it on multiple networks too, but initial timeout stays the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like ES connection is timing out. check if ES is accessible on the ip address you are providing. if you are using public IP, try changing it to private IP

Comment: Yeah, changed the public IP to private and it drastically reduced the ingestion time from 20 minutes to 12 seconds. Thanks mate!

Comment: Hi, I'm in the same situation but I don't know how to fix it. Currently I'm working on docker containers, one for ES and one for Spark. They are in different projects (docker-compose) and Spark is able to reach ES. Any suggestion?